# How to add PR titles into the Pull Requests view of GitHub Organization (Multibranch pipeline) in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Is this possible to add Pull Request titles to this table?

[image: Pull Requests View]

Comment: Found another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656798/rename-pr-jobs-in-the-pull-requests-tab-of-a-multibranch-pipeline-in-jenkins

Comment: Created the issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-60082